# Flutter ListTile leading image placement

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure how to move the image all the way to the left. I don't want that leading tile space. What can I use to accomplish this?

```
      ListTile(
          dense: true,
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => UserAlert(
                uid: users[index]['uid'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          tileColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            users[index]['displayName'],
          ),
          leading: Positioned(
            child: Container(
              width: 50.0,
              height: 50.0,
              child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                placeholder: 'assets/images/default-logo.png',
                image: users[index]['photoURL'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control it with the **contentPadding** of the ListTile:

```dart
ListTile(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10.0,
          ),
...
)
```

Just be sure to add paddings to children of the ListTile so that they do not touch the border of the ListTile.